# _mm256_movemask_epi8 to uint64_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion, intrinsics, sign-extension

Can someone please explain me why **tr2** and **tr4** show different result:

```
auto test1 = _mm256_set1_epi8(-1);

    uint64_t tr2 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(test1);
    uint32_t tr3 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(test1);
    uint64_t tr4 = tr3;
```

_mm256_movemask_epi8(test1) should return int32, so assigning it to int64 should just assign lower bits.

Instead, **tr2** prints 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and **tr4** prints 0x00000000FFFFFFFF

Is there any performance in doing it as tr4?

I'm new to both C++ and intrinsics so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 C++ compiler.

Comment: `_mm256_movemask_epi8` returns an `int` (which is `signed` of course), so it's just the usual C (or C++) type promotion rules. Nothing to do with SIMD or intrinsics *per se*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul above said, this has to do with assignment of signed/unsigned with bigger integers.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int32_t negInt = -1;
    uint32_t unInt = static_cast<uint32_t>(negInt);
    int64_t negBigInt = static_cast<int64_t>(negInt);
    uint64_t unBigInt = static_cast<uint64_t>(negInt);
    uint64_t fromUnsigned = static_cast<uint64_t>(unInt);

    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << negInt << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << unInt << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << negBigInt << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << unBigInt << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << fromUnsigned << "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
0x00000000ffffffff
0x00000000ffffffff
0xffffffffffffffff
0xffffffffffffffff
0x00000000ffffffff
```

So Paul is right, but notably this doesn't happen if you assign a *signed* number to higher bit-width fields.